# Entity Framework - 1 to 1 relationship where one end is not a primary key

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'd like to define a relationship in an Entity Framework data model that is 1-to-1 with one end as a primary key of one table and the other end a foreign key on another. For instance:

```
table: aspnet_Users
w/ col: UserId guid Primary Key
```

with the UserId property of the aspnet_Users table related to the AspUserId column of the User table:

```
table: User
w /col: UserId int Primary Key
w /col: AspUserId guid
```

When I try to do this I get an error saying that since the AspUserId field is not a primary key of it's table that won't work:

> Error 21 Error 113: Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'User' in relationship 'FK_User_aspnet_Users'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be *.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign keys need to map to primary keys. Otherwise, the below records could happen:

```
aspnet_Users
UserId 
11111111
11111111
22222222

User
UserId AspUserId
1      11111111
2      11111111
```

And that doesn't make sense - and breaks your 1-1 cardinality.

However - that being said (looking at an old membership db - yuck), `UserId` field on `dbo.aspnet_Users` *is* a primary key.

Are you sure you have your foreign key on the correct table? Does `dbo.aspnet_Users` on your database have the PK for `UserId`.

Also - try not to map the membership tables - it will be a world of pain. The relationships in the membership schema are *highly complicated*.

Just map your own User table. It's fine to have the FK for database-side work (auditing, stored procedures, triggers, etc).

But from the model side - you should be interacting with your User entity via EF, and your aspnet_Users (Membership) entity via the Membership Provider API.

If you need to "stitch them together" in your code (often the case), then encapsulate that behind a service.

Comment: Yes indeed the UserId field on the aspnet_Users is a primary key, the issue I seem to be having is with the AspNetUserId field which is not the PK of it's table: User. If I could go back and do it all over again I suppose it's possible I could have made the PK of the user table a guid and match the UserId field of the aspnet_Users table, I'm not sure that would in fact be worth the change but I think it would fix my 1-to-1 EF model relationship issue. I suppose I was hoping there would be some other kind of workaround.

Comment: @BrooklynDev - `AspNetUserId` field does not need to be a PK of the User table. It's a foreign key. Foreign keys map to a PK on another table. Are you sure you created the FK on the `User` table and not on the `aspnet_Users` table? Can you show the CREATE TABLE statement for `Users` table?

Comment: Yes I'm sure AspUserId is a FK, my issue seems to be the EF wants that foreign key to also be the primary key of it's table if it'll allow me to define a 1-to-1 relationship with it: create table added below:

Comment: Ahh ok - maybe it does need `AspUserId` as the PK on `User` too. Try removing the `UserId` column and making `AspUserId` the PK/FK. As i said though, i'd be surprised if you even manage to get your model validating with the membership tables on there. I still recommend using the provider API. But it's your call.

Answer (score 0):

In response to a poster the User table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [UserId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AspUserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_User_aspnet_Users] FOREIGN     KEY([AspUserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[aspnet_Users] ([UserId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_User_aspnet_Users]
GO
```