# EF Code First 4.1: how to map Member.UserId to the aspnet_Users.UserId?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, ef-code-first

I have a `Member` class:

```
public class Member
{
    // key 
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    // some other fields
}
```

Also I have a `aspnet_Users` table with has `UserId` primary column.

We can:

1). Add additional property `MembershipUser` to the `Member` object and get it's value by calling `Membership.GetUser(this.UserId)` method.

Also I've add

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Members]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Members_aspnet_Users] FOREIGN KEY([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[aspnet_Users] ([UserId])");
```

to the `DataContext.Seed()` method to ensure that `Member` can not be added without  `aspnet_Users` account.

2). Use fluent API in `OnModelCreating`. If this a good case how to map them correctly?

What's the best choice? Any thoughts?

Comment: Be careful with adding referential constraints like this to the ASP.Net Membership tables.  Because now when you add a user to your Member Table you must know the ASPNet Member you are adding for.  You would not want to insert/Update/Delete from the ASPNet Membership tables using EF. And this can cause some difficulties in the end.  In addtion, Ideally this would be a one to one relationship.  But you would be creating the relationship off a Field that I believe is not your primary key.

Comment: Thanks for mention. I think it should be a one-to-one relation and UserId should be the key. This situation is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485350/entity-framework-1-to-1-relationship-where-one-end-is-not-a-primary-key

Answer (score 1):

No matter how I tried to avoid it, I've found the best approach is to [implement my own MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) and have it use my model, rather than trying to shoehorn my model into the built-in membership provider.

If you are going down the other route you have to map the ASP.NET Membership tables to your domain and derive your Member class from the ASP_User class (or vice versa if you want to ensure that all Users you create are Members). In the end, I've discovered that although it seems like more effort up front, implementing MembershipProvider is the easier approach.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  Don't add foreign key constraints against the aspnet_* tables.  It's a recipe for trouble.  Membership is plug-in type system, and you have to treat it as a black box.

Simply lookup the data in your tables with the MembershipUser.ProviderUserKey as it's value.  Something like this:

```
from m in Member where UserID == (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey select t;
```

Comment: But what happens if the user is deleted (may be by someone's mistake)? How do we get existing data to be syncronized with the newly created (recreated) user's ID?

Comment: @Azat - you just set the new ProviderUserKey as the key into your users table.